# How can I use cookie with http Thrift?

Tags: cookies, thrift, setcookie, thrift-protocol, spark-thriftserver

So, I'm communicating with the server using THttpClient of Thrift. The server is already sending the set-cookie header, but I was not sure on how to extract that from the response (in client side), and send back that cookie as the header of the subsequent requests..

Thanks.

Comment: What language are you using?